# Need to get feedback (Form ) from clients via email(Outlook 2010).

Tags: 2010, outlook

How to design a form in outlook 2010, which will help client or end user to provide a feedback. The form shoudl be a part of email, which will help client to submit their feedbacks online.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, the form can only be replied as a Email.. which doesn't make sense... What you can do is create a InfoPath/List Form and provide a link in the email, can you please tell your complete scenario!

Comment: since you posted here were assuming you want to post results back to SharePoint with this method. There is no mechanism for that, however #Arsalans approach would work and would even be preferable to Outlook forms.